# Add leaf as well as non-leaf nodes at the same level in a GWT CellBrowser or Cell Tree

Tags: gwt, cellbrowser

I want to add `non-leaf` as well as `leaf` `nodes` at a same level in a GWT CellBrowser/ Cell Tree. Can i do it? if yes, how? Because while returning `DefaultNodeInfo` I am not getting an option to return both kind of `ListDataProviders`.

Comment: I found out a way. Don't worry Guys.

Comment: It will be good if you can share your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to create a superclass or interface Node, which your NonLeafNode and your LeafNode class extend / implement:

```
public class NonLeafNode extends Node{
}
```

or

```
public class NonLeafNode implements Node{
}
```

Then you can give the CellBrowser or CellTree a single ListDataProvider which provides both types of node. In the underlying model, e.g. a TreeViewModel, you need to adjust the isLeaf(Object o) and the getNodeInfo(T value) functions as follows:

```
public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
    if (value instanceof NonLeafNode) return true;
    if (value instanceof LeafNode) return false;
    return false;
}

public <T> getNodeInfo(T value){
    if (value instanceof NonLeafNode) 
         // return node info for non-leaf-node
        ;
    else if (value instanceof LeafNode)
         // return node info for leaf node
        ;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @SusannBrunner
This method is good too. I created a class with a self referential array and checked if array is null then leaf and if not null the non-leaf.

Answer (score 0):

My way out!

```
private static class Folder
        {
            private final String        name;

            private final List<Folder>  folder  = new ArrayList<Folder>();

            public Folder(String name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public String getName()
            {
                return name;
            }

            public void addFolder(Folder p)
            {
                this.folder.add(p);
            }

            public List<Folder> getFolders()
            {
                return folder;
            }
        }
```

then in the CustomTreeModel that we create override the isLeaf as follows

```
        public boolean isLeaf(Object value)
        {
            if (value instanceof String || (value instanceof Folder && ((Folder) value).getFolders().isEmpty()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```